# Help me with AMD integrated graphics please

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, proprietary

I am trying to install Proprietary Graphics drivers(AMD) but I am finding it difficult to do it.

I followed a youtube tutorial "how to run a .run file" but after that it shows me this:-

Please check the screenshot and help.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. It appears to be working on something.

Comment: But anyway, I recommend using the Additional Drivers app that comes pre-installed on Ubuntu. If your integrated graphics have proprietary drivers, they'll show up there for you to install. It's safer and easier.

Comment: ..and how do I do that? Am sorry but am new to Linux.

Comment: Just search for it using Dash (the Ubutu logo at the top of the launcher/dock)

Comment: anyway I am going to get a new graphics card today but it would've helped me learn something new. :/

Comment: Learning about Ubuntu is always good ;). But I wouldn't recommend going into AMD's .run drivers. I've never had good experiences with that method of installation.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I closed it out of frustration e.e

Comment: That... Could be bad. Open a new terminal and run `sudo apt-get purge fglrx` then `sudo apt-get instal -f` quickly.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yeah it seems like that. I had an old card which I just sold today and wanted to use integrated amd graphics for a couple of hours more. you know.

Comment: @Zacharee1 really? O.O

Comment: Well if it was actually doing something, it was probably in the middle of installing the drivers. How long did you wait?

Comment: maybe for a minute or so and I used my useless brain to find out whats happening. Gave some commands as you can see in the pic and just closed it.

Comment: I don't see any commands, but a minute is not a very long time. See if you can do the driver installation from the Additional Drivers app. If it errors out, I may be able to help with that.

Comment: Additional drivers app as in? o.o

Comment: It's literally called that. Just search for it.

Comment: I posted something here as an answer, although its not an answer, still it helps. I guess.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, which I recommend, since posting as an answer should actually be an answer ;)

Comment: Anyway, though, since you have integrated graphics, you don't need the drivers.

Comment: oh I see :O. So I guess I must wait till I get a new graphics card.

Comment: Yeah. Use the app, though.

Comment: hmmmm, thanks a lot for resolving my query but hey I posted another question related to restricted extras, pls do check that question as well if possible :p

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Look at this image. This is what I got after running additional drivers app.